# How to put Line break in javascript ?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put line break in javascript. I have used `<br/>, \n and %0D%0A` but nothing happened.

Here is my code:

```
var textpara = 'This is dummy text. It will blink and then show.';
```

I want this:

```
This is dummy text.
It will blink and then show.
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: How are you showing or using the string?

Comment: Do you need to display the text somewhere in the page, in the console or in an alert box?

Comment: Show the surrounding code.

Comment: The above code work for me

Comment: Yes i have to show this text in console.

Comment: You should put clarifications into the question by editing it. And I doubt that you don’t really mean the console. (How would you blink text there, and why?)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the text in the console, you can use the backslash-newline trick:

```
var textpara = 'This is dummy text. \
It will blink and then show.';

console.log(textpara);
```

Alternatively, add the newline like this:

```
var textpara = "This is dummy text. \nIt will blink and then show.";
console.log(textpara);
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding "\n" should do the job.

Try this:

javascript:

```
var textpara = "This is dummy text." + "\n" + "It will blink and then show.";

alert(textpara);
```

on your browser's url bar.

I have tested it and it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script lang="JavaScript" >
var textpara = 'This is dummy text. <br/>It will blink and then show.';
document.write(textpara);
</script>
```

this works too.

Output:

```
This is dummy text. 
It will blink and then show.
```